# How to automatically add `.js` to module address auto fixing?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

In VSCode is function "Show Fixes" with `Import 'someting' from module "addres"`.
It adds the import automatically.

Unfortunately, it does not add the ".js" ending to the address.

What to do in VSCode configs, to automatically add `.js` to the module address?

Answer (score 3):

Check if [VSCode 1.44 (March 2020)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/71643d75d942e2c32cfd781c2b5322521775fb4a/release-notes/v1_44.md#finer-grained-control-over-auto-import-style-in-javascript) can help with:

> ### Finer grained control over auto import style in JavaScript

> The new **`javascript.preferences.importModuleSpecifierEnding`** setting lets you control the style of imports that VS Code's auto imports use.
>
> This can be useful if you are writing code for platforms such as browsers that support native ES6 modules.
>
> Possible values are:
>
> - **`auto`** — The default. Uses the project's jsconfig to determine the import style to use
> - **`minimal`** — Use's node.js style imports. This shortens imports for src/component/index.js to src/component.
> - **`index`** — Include the index part of the path as well. This shortens src/component/index.js to src/component/index.
> - **`js`** — **Use the full path, including the file extension (`.js`)**.

Comment: How is this done in Visual Studio 2019? It has the same problem.

Comment: @hk1980 To my knowledge, this is not supported in VS2019 (and Visual Studio is very different from Visual Studio Code). Check the [VS Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/) for a suitable extension.